# (pygame) unexpectly crashes when inserted color code

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm learning how to build python games and was following a tutorial online how to program a simple pygame, unfortunately I was stopped at what seems like a very basic part. The tutorial is pretty old so the likely-hood that I will get an answer back soon is slim and I've tried looking this up but I can't find one with a similar issue. The code works fine without the color input `GameDisplay.fill(white)`

I'm running off a mac version 10.11, and coding with python 2.7.10 for pygame. I get no traceback error on the python shell, I just get a "Python quit unexpectedly" and wonder if I'm missing an important Python input?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("This Thing")

white = (255,255,255)


GameQuit = False


while not GameQuit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameQuit = True

    GameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: On my linux machine with `Python 2.7.6` it work, I saw a white rectangle and it doesen't crash...

Comment: I also just tested this on windows 10, it was fine. Let me try it on my mac and see if that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pygame crashes when fill(color) method is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221463/pygame-crashes-when-fillcolor-method-is-used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code on both windows 10 with python 2.7.10 and mac 10.10 with python 2.7.9 (not exactly the same, but close). Neither of these would replicate the same behavior. Try uninstalling and reinstalling pygame.

Comment: Just tried this but it's still pulling up the python error. Let me try downloading python and pygame for my windows computer and see if it does it there.

Comment: Wow, that's really strange. I would try it out, but I don't feel like upgrading to El Capitan. It seems like pygame and 10.11 don't get along very well, https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the help! My mac was new at bestbuy so I decided to get a windows laptop instead of mac (there were programs I was used to running and weren't compatible with mac unless I were to do some loop holes lol) all-in-all I did a switch. I tried the code out again after re-downloading, everything is working perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question and luckily, my question answered by someone called numbermaniac who figured out how to do it. Here is the question I asked that was solved by him:

[pygame crashes when fill(color) method is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221463/pygame-crashes-when-fillcolor-method-is-used)