# pygame crashes when fill(color) method is used

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

My pygame code crashes somehow when I use the `fill()` method.

First off I found there is [an exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311844/pygame-unexpectly-crashes-when-inserted-color-code) on this website by some one else who probably watched the same pygame tutorial as I did, but the problem is not actually solved on there and that's why I'm creating this duplicate question (not really a duplicate since the original question asked by someone else wasn't solved either).

My code is down below. The part of code that is causing the crashing is the `GameDisplay.fill(black)` part.

I know this, because when I delete that line everything works fine. My pygame version is the same as the python I have (2.7), and both are 32 bit. The device I'm using is a macbook air.

I have already tried reinstalling my python and pygame, but the code would still crash. I only have a macbook and cannot do this on a windows computer like the other guy who asked the same question, so I am wondering if there are anyways to make this work? Help will be appreciated!

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()
GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("rooms")

GameExit = False
while not GameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            GameExit = True

    GameDisplay.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Could you please post the exception or error message you are getting when it crashes?

Comment: The error pop up screen have a lot of words in it i'm not sure if this is what you want:  Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
  Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at   0x0000000000000000
  Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Comment: The problem seems to be about the system. Especially iOS. When googled, the issues pop up is about apple products.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting but how do you add line breaks for comments?   adding 2 spaces doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: There is no defined line break to my knowledge, but you can use `this inline formatting`. By the way, the adress 0x000000.. etc, corresponds to the null pointer which should be uncallable, and your program shouldn't have tried to access it in your program. You can do some research on this behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't look like anyone has filed this as a bug for Pygame. You may want to [add a new issue](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues?q=EXC_BAD_ACCESS) if you plan on using the library on future projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on my Macbook Air. Pygame can create a screen, but whenever it tries to touch it, it will crash with a Segmentation error (this is the SIGSEGV you see in your error). This is because Pygame relies on the SDL framework, and the built-in one on Mac is ... not perfect.

From the official SDL website, go to [the download page](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) and get the runtime library 1.2.15 for Mac. Open the .dmg you downloaded and you'll be given an SDL.framework file. Open /Library/Frameworks in Finder and move the framework file there. (If it asks to replace, I selected Merge, but I'm sure Replace should also work.)

This fixed Pygame for me. I hope it works for you too!

Comment: you are the MOST BRILLIANT man on earth!
I Read hundreds of post that didn't solve my problem, and you did with the simplest solution. I owe you months of work, seriously!!!!

Comment: Haha, no problem! :)