# Segmentation fault: 11 when trying to run Pygame

Tags: python, terminal, pygame

I am using OSX 10.11.6, Python 2.17.12 and Pygame 1.9.1.
I made this simple program that should display a black rectangle in the middle of a white field. However, when I try to run it I get an error saying:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work. Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameExit = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [400, 300, 20, 20])

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Does someone know how I can solve this issue? Thanks in advance!
Note: I am writing my code in Atom, and running it in Terminal using this command:

```
$ python2.7-32 slither.py
```

Comment: That code works alright with `pygame==1.9.2a0` + `Python 2.7.11` on windows. I'd recommend you start commenting lines till determine at what exactly point you get the seg fault. For instance, what's going on when you do `import pygame; pygame.init()`, does it crash?

Comment: It's definitely something with your installation.  I'm on 10.11.6, Pygame 1.9.2a0 and Python 2.7.12 & 3.5.2.  Is there a reason you're running an older version of pygame?  1.9.1 is a 2012 release.

Comment: When I try to download the 1.9.2 version, it says this is not possible because it is not compatible with my OSX version. Therefore I downloaded Python 2.7 from python.org along with Pygame 1.9.1

Comment: I use 1.9.2 all the time on OS X.  "it says" - what says that?  How are you trying to install?  Installing on OS X used to be a pain, but now you can just do "pip install pygame".  I just did it on a classroom set of Macbooks running El Capitan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pygame crashes when fill(color) method is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221463/pygame-crashes-when-fillcolor-method-is-used)

Comment: I already answered the same question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37235340/3150837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a flaw in the built-in SDL library that Pygame depends on. Pygame can create a screen, but attempting to touch it will immediately crash it with Segmentation error 11.

From the official SDL website, go to [the download page](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) and get the runtime library 1.2.15 for Mac. Open the .dmg you downloaded and you'll be given an SDL.framework file. Open /Library/Frameworks in Finder and move the framework file there. You may need to select Replace.