# Python freezes and crashes when using .fill and .blit respectively for both problems

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pygame

On my mac, i'm trying to make a game and learning how to use pygame but every time I type .fill(), my game freezes.

Also, when I type .blit(), python launcher immediately crashes:

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('carcopy.png')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))


x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    car(x,y)
    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pygame crashes when fill(color) method is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221463/pygame-crashes-when-fillcolor-method-is-used)

Answer (score 0):

Is it really freezes? Put the rendering functions in the right order. Screen fill goes first, because it paints the whole screen with white color. Then you should put your blit functions to render your objects on the cleared screen.

```
gameDisplay.fill(white)
car(x,y)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I did but it still freezes or crashes

Comment: Well, your code works fine on my Windows machine. I also changed the picture load a bit, imported os, got the .py file path and then loaded the picture using its full path.

Comment: Don't worry I finally found someone who fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221463/pygame-crashes-when-fillcolor-method-is-used